# Ionic Push Notification Error 403

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement an application that send push notification to some tokens registered.

I followed this guide: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push
and I'm trying this code below:

```
var CribbioApp = angular.module('CribbioApp', []); //Nome dell'applicazione (definito in data-ng-app)
```

CribbioApp.controller('CribbioController', function ($scope, $http) {//Definizione del controller (definito in data-ng-controller)
    $scope.invianotifica = function(){
      window.alert('Porta pazienza!');

```
  // Define relevant info
  var privateKey = 'AIzaSyBfCGRs5F_dEp2Qd3Fag3mYVP44k9X4r4c';
  var tokens = ['coHMIQnnWwU:APA91bGqmSZpcrbfDm3Hx_E7Loq9Y78AEXRfOX1t_TZ2IQumszLyPGQhfche4X5N0DAqbQFLuTFVYRQ055M3U-G-JlGwPtEd4kj31xtT0jswfj-ATfOefsLWG2dfVaffb5dFHzJUplNd'];
  var appId = '390838258677';

  // Encode your key
  var auth = btoa(privateKey + ':');

  // Build the request object
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Ionic-Application-Id': appId,
      'Authorization': 'basic ' + auth
    },
    data: {
      "tokens": tokens,
      "notification": {
        "alert":"Hello World!"
      }
    }
  };

  // Make the API call
  $http(req).success(function(resp){
    // Handle success
    console.log("Ionic Push: Push success!");
  }).error(function(error){
    // Handle error
    console.log("Ionic Push: Push error...");
  });
```

But I get this error:

```
POST https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push 403 (Forbidden)
```

I found that error 403, means that token is invalid (correct???), but i'm sure that is it valid!
How do I solve?

Comment: No 403 can mean many things. If you are talking about HTTP 403, then [403==forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Comment: Anyone? I have still this problem

Comment: I've given you response and a link. *"403 can mean many things."* You need to figure out which of the different 403 is firing. You have the code. I do not have the code.

Comment: I published the code I used

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean. Did you publish your App? Did you post your code somewhere? Do you need more help?

Comment: Hi Simone,
Did you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: Not.. I dind't found a solution :(

Comment: Have you gone through this link:

https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/